# Are there any problems with using an average of percentages for a 2 proportion z-test?

Tags: z-test

Let's say I have a 2 groups of test scores (ranging from 0% to 100%), and I wanted to compare their means to see if there was anything significant. I know I can average the test scores to obtain a proportion for each sample. Can I safely use a 2 proportion z-test for this scenario?

From my understanding, the 2 proportion z-test is used for dichotomous data, and treating each result as a success/failure, and taking the average based off of that. What I am doing instead is counting each individual as a sample value from 0.0 to 1.0. I'm not sure if that is acceptable or not.

Comment: It looks like you are measuring a response of each individual on a 0-100 rating scale, is that correct understanding? Then why not use a test for continuous data, the t test or Mann-Whitney?

Comment: @ttnphns - My major "fear" is that if the results are close to one end of the spectrum, i.e. close to 0% or 100%; I don't believe the z-test range "caps" the values at 0 or 100, so I'll see strange values like -15%, or 102% as part of the CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I safely use a 2 proportion z-test for this scenario?

No. [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) tie the [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Expectation) and the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Variance) together in a very particular way. There is no reason to believe test scores would follow this distribution; for example, test scores for "Film Studies 107: 80's Screwball Comedies" may have a mean of 90% and a standard deviation of only 3%, while "Calculus 256: Abandon all Hope, Ye Who Enter Here" might have a mean of 40% and a standard deviation of 50%.

You should probably use use the usual t-test instead. This avoids the problem by estimating the mean and variance separately, and even corrects for the uncertainty of the estimate of the variance.